# Using a camera in-app | Not requiring native camera

Tags: flutter

I am building a camera app where I would like the camera to be in-app. Currently, when the camera screen opens, and you click the photo button, it then opens the native device camera, so technically, you have two click the take photo button twice to take a photo.

I would like to just utilize the camera preview to take the picture, and not have to also open the native camera.

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  Function setData;
  Camera({Key key, this.setData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<Camera> {
  CameraController controller;
  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIndex;
  String imgPath;
  var image;

  Future _openGallery() async {
    image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (widget.setData != null) {
      widget.setData(image);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
      cameras = availableCameras;

      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCameraIndex = 0;
        });
        _initCameraController(cameras[selectedCameraIndex]).then((void v) {});
      } else {
        print('No camera available');
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error :${err.code}Error message : ${err.message}');
    });
  }

  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }

      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: 120,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _cameraToggleRowWidget(),
                      _cameraControlWidget(context),
                      Spacer()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Loading',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    }

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }

  Widget _cameraControlWidget(context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.camera,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                // getImage();
                _openGallery();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _cameraToggleRowWidget() {
    if (cameras == null || cameras.isEmpty) {
      return Spacer();
    }
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    CameraLensDirection lensDirection = selectedCamera.lensDirection;

    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          onPressed: _onSwitchCamera,
          icon: Icon(
            _getCameraLensIcon(lensDirection),
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 24,
          ),
          label: Text(
            '${lensDirection.toString().substring(lensDirection.toString().indexOf('.') + 1).toUpperCase()}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  IconData _getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
    switch (direction) {
      case CameraLensDirection.back:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera;
      case CameraLensDirection.front:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera_solid;
      case CameraLensDirection.external:
        return Icons.camera;
      default:
        return Icons.device_unknown;
    }
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    String errorText = 'Error:${e.code}\nError message : ${e.description}';
    print(errorText);
  }

  void _onSwitchCamera() {
    selectedCameraIndex =
        selectedCameraIndex < cameras.length - 1 ? selectedCameraIndex + 1 : 0;
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    _initCameraController(selectedCamera);
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use this package [camera: ^0.8.0](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) it will allow you to open camera in app using its `CameraPreview`